# PHP - Protected/Abstract method to use class declared in child class

Tags: php, abstract-class

I have an abstract class, in which I want to call method, from a class that is declared in the child (extending) class. An example looks like this:

The abstract class:

```
abstract class NumberGenerator
{
    protected function generate($input){
        return MyClass::MyMethod($input);
    }
}
```

My child/extending class:

```
use TomsFolder\MyClass;
use MyFolder\NumberGenerator;

class TomsNumberGenerator extends NumberGenerator
{
    public function generate(string $applicantId): string
    {   
        return $this->generate();
    }
}
```

Another child/extending class:

```
use DavesFolder\MyClass;
use MyFolder\NumberGenerator;

class DavesNumberGenerator extends NumberGenerator
{
    public function generate(string $applicantId): string
    {   
        return $this->generate();
    }
}
```

So I want to call MyClass::MyMethod in NumberGenerator. However it is only imported in TomsNumberGenerator.

The reason I want to do it like is because, I have classes like DavesNumberGenerator which calls a different MyClass.

When I try this, I get 'MyClass is not found in NumberGenerator'. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Are you using some namespaces in the file containing the `NumberGenerator` class?

Comment: No the namespaces are different.

Comment: By the way, if you're calling the `MyClass:MyMethod` statically, you're doing it wrong, there's a missing colon, it should be `MyClass::MyMethod`. Then try to use the namespace `use MyFolder\MyClass;` BEFORE creating the `NumberGenerator` class.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: The classes are defined in different files. I should've been clearer on that. What do you mean by, before creating NumberGenerator?

Comment: Put the `use MyFolder\MyClass;` statement on the beginning of the file containing the `NumberGenerator` class.

Comment: I can't do that because I have several MyFolder\MyClass instances. A better way to put it would be TomFolder\MyClass, and DaveFolder\MyClass. I need TomsNumberGenerator (or DavesNumberGenerator) to specify which class to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the namespace `use` statement before the actual class:

NumberGenerator.php

```
use MyFolder\MyClass;

abstract class NumberGenerator
{
    protected function generate($input){
        return MyClass::MyMethod($input);
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Try this:

NumberGenerator.php

```
abstract class NumberGenerator
{
    protected function generate($class_name, $input){
        return call_user_func($class_name . '::MyMethod', $input);
    }
}
```

TomsNumberGenerator.php

```
use TomsFolder\MyClass;
use MyFolder\NumberGenerator;

class TomsNumberGenerator extends NumberGenerator
{
    public function generate(string $applicantId): string
    {   
        return $this->generate(get_class(new MyClass()), $applicantId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have clarified this in the original question now. Since I have different instances of MyClass, I can't specify this in the NumberGenerator class. It will have to be specified in whichever class is extending the NumberGenerator.

Comment: I tried passing the class name to the abstract method earlier but couldn't get it to work, so this helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use interface for this.
You can do the following

1. Create `MyClassInterface`

```
interface MyClassInterface {
    public function MyMethod();
}
```

2. Implement this interface in some classes

```
class MyClass1 implements MyClassInterface {
    public function MyMethod() {
        // implementation
    }
}

class MyClass2 implements MyClassInterface {
    public function MyMethod() {
        // implementation 2
    }
}
```

3. Add abstract method to `NumberGenerator`

```
abstract class NumberGenerator {
    abstract protected function GetMyClass(): MyClassInterface;

    protected function generate($input){
        return $this->GetMyClass()->MyMethod($input);
    }
}
```

4. Implement `GetMyClass` function inside child classes

```
class TomsNumberGenerator extends NumberGenerator
{
    protected function GetMyClass(): MyClassInterface {
        return new MyClass1();
    }
}
```

```
class DavesNumberGenerator extends NumberGenerator
{
    protected function GetMyClass(): MyClassInterface {
        return new MyClass2();
    }
}
```

**PS** If you want to use static, you can change abstract inside `NumberGenerator` class, to change `string`. In this case, your `generate` will look like this:

```
protected function generate($input){
    return call_user_func($this->GetMyClass() . '::MyMethod', [$input]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured I'd have to use an interface if this didn't work. Thanks for breaking it down.

Comment: Do you know if there is a reason, that an abstract class cannot look for a class included in the child class? A const defined in the child class can be fetched using 'static'.

Comment: @fractal5 I don't know exactly, but I think that this diverges with OOP rules. I mean child class can override the behavior of parent class, but parent class can't influence on the behavior of child class. Child class know about it's parent, but parent class doesn't know about it's children